# update-grub error : resume=UUID=xxx not found

Tags: grub2, suspend, swap, hibernate, uuid

I'm currently trying to get hibernation working and I therefore change the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` to `"resume=UUID=xxx"` where xxx is my swap partition UUID. But it shows me the error `error :  resume=UUID=xxx not found`. Why is this ? I can't find any answer about this on the internet, that's quite surprising.

EDIT : when rebooting I have 2 errors : `/dev/dm-0 closed with error` and same for `/dev/dm-1`, which are my swap partitions (results of `swapon -s`)

Comment: You might find the answer here to help you fix this:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1212028/the-initframs-will-attempt-to-resume-from-when-updating-kubuntu