# The initframs will attempt to resume from... when updating (K)ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot

I've got a dual-boot setup, Kubuntu (installed last) and Xubunthu.

sda:

sda1 /boot/efi

sda2 SWAP

sda3 / (Xubunthu)

sda4 /home (Xubunthu)

sda5 / Kubuntu

When I tun sudo dist-upgrade in Kubuntu I always get :
update0initframs: generating /boot/initrd.img-X.X.X-XX-generic
The initframs will attempt to resume fom /dev/sda2
(UID=XXXXXXX)
Set the RESUME variable to override this

swapon -s shows that Kubuntu is using SWAP partition that was already present (Xubunthu preinstalled).

What does it meant? Is there a conflict or something?

How do I fix this (should I?)

Thanx a lot!

Comment: Both can use/share the swap partition (unless you want to use it for hibernation, then they can't share as the hibernated system will be using it). You however didn't provide release info, as recent releases use swap files rather than swap partitions on default installs. I also note you appear to have a single /home partition; that can create problems if releases vary (*I used to do it, but decided the problems weren't worth the hassle so I don't anymore... issues vary on release & really the software installed & used*)

Comment: Hello. Thanx for the info.

Kubuntu 19.10, Xubunthu 18.04

home partition is for xubunthu only.  Kubuntu's home folder is on the / partition (sda5). i can move Xubunthu's  home partition to sda3 /  if it's  a problem.

Comment: I don't believe you have a problem with swap; but I'd wait for others to read it. FYI: I shared a /home partition for a number of years, then discovered `evolution` (mail program; MUA storing mail locally) had new features & I started using those new features; any messages that were 'colorized' by later program became invisible to the older program sharing the mail database (when using older release). It's older software didn't know of changes, so ignored all those messages. Had I not have used the new features I'd not have known. That's example, also had issues with other programs too..

Answer (score 1):

This just means that the UUID in `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` is missing or does not match the swap partition.

To fix, edit the file and add the correct UUID.

If file does not exist, create it and add a line like `RESUME=UUID=whatever`

For example, on one of my systems, the swap partition has a UUID of `adc97911-6d93-4094-8ec4-15cab05377e7`, so the line looks like

`RESUME=UUID=adc97911-6d93-4094-8ec4-15cab05377e7`

Then run `sudo update-initramfs -u`